# A webpage reveals a submenu when clicked. How can I identify the JS function doing it?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have a web page that has a side menu.

When the user clicks on the side menu, a sub menu is displayed.

It was working but is now broken.  To fix it I need to find the JavaScript function that is being run when the click happens.

I'm using Chrome in this case but I'll use whatever tools will get the job done.

How can I track down the specific function being run?

The source looks like this:

```
    {/* Start navigation - blog */}
    <li className="submenu">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span className="icon"><i className="fa fa-globe" /></span>
        <span className="text">Blog</span>
        <span className="arrow" />
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="blog-grid.html">Grid</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog-list.html">List</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog-single.html">Single</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    {/* End navigation - blog */}
```

Comment: You can pause whenever a click event handler is executed. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-on-javascript-event-listeners

Comment: if thats pure html perhaps you should try replacing `className` with `class`. maybe it got renamed after a refactor by mistake or something. worth giving it a chance.